# filter by count of reverse lookup

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models, for example,

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    teams = models.ManyToManyField("Team", related_name="student", blank=True)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=160)
```

I want to retrieve all the teams which is not assigned to any student , ie all teams where students.count() is 0. How can i query this?

I have tried

```
   Team.objects.filter(student=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`isnull`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull) filter

```
Team.objects.filter(student__isnull=True)
```